# ¿Cómo enviar en el cuerpo de una función mail(), elementos de un array?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Hola estoy diseñando un carrito de compras y quería enviar en una función mail los diferentes productos con sus cantidades y precios totales que el usuario compró al este presionar en el botón "pay" de mercado pago.

```
session_start();

require_once("../clases/Producto.php");


$total=$_POST['total'];

$destinatario = $_POST["email"]; 

$data=serialize($_SESSION['carrito']);

 $carritoObtenido=unserialize($data);

$asunto = "Este mensaje es de prueba"; 

$cuerpo = ' 

<html> 

<head> 

<title>Prueba de correo</title> 

</head> 

<body> 

<h1>Cubiertas Oeste</h1> 

<p> 

Usted ha comprado los siguientes productos;

'foreach ($carritoObtenido as $producto) {

        //si la cantidad del producto es diferente de  0 muestro la 
información del carrito
        if($producto->cantidad != 0){
            $producto->marca;
            $producto->modelo;
            $producto->cantidad;
            'total:'$producto->cantidad*$producto->precio''
        }
    }
    '

</p> 

<p>Por un total de:'$total=$_POST['total']'</p>

</body> 

</html> 

'; 


//para el envío en formato HTML 

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 

$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 


//dirección del remitente 

$headers .= "From: Cubiertas Oeste <NeumaticosOeste@gmail.com>\r\n"; 


//dirección de respuesta, si queremos que sea distinta que la del remitente 

$headers .= "Reply-To: tatyrod@gmail.com\r\n"; 


//ruta del mensaje desde origen a destino 

$headers .= "Return-path: holahola@desarrolloweb.com\r\n"; 

//direcciones que recibián copia 
$headers .= "Cc: tatyrod@gmail.com\r\n"; 


mail($destinatario,$asunto,$cuerpo,$headers);
```

Alguna idea para poder realizar esto ???

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, puedes explicar qué has intentado y por qué el codigo presentado no hace lo que quieres? Donde está la funcion `mail`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes problemas en la utilización de HTML combinado con PHP. Por ejemplo aquí:

`Usted ha comprado los siguientes productos;
'  foreach ($carritoObtenido as $producto) {` se ve claramente que no has entendido bien el **concepto**.

Cuando combinas HTML/PHP es necesario tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

a. Si estás en HTML no tienes que terminar las líneas con `;` ni necesitas usar comillas `'` para unir cadenas. En HTML escribes como si estuvieras en un editor de textos, usando las etiquetas indicadas de apertura y cierre para cada cosa: `<p>Párrafo</p>` `<div>Un div</div>`, etc.

b. Cuando pasas de HTML a PHP tienes que indicar que abres un bloque PHP, poniendo esto: `<?php`

c. Cuando pasas de PHP a HTML tienes que indicarlo cerrando el bloque PHP con esto: `?>`

d. Para guardar desde PHP contenido que mostrarás en el HTML no tienes por qué hacer esto:

```
$cuerpo = ' 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Prueba de correo</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1>Cubiertas Oeste</h1> 
<p> 
Usted ha comprado los siguientes productos;
'foreach ($carritoObtenido as $producto) {
/*si la cantidad del producto es diferente de  0 muestro la informacion del carrito*/
        if($producto->cantidad != 0){
            $producto->marca;
            $producto->modelo;
            $producto->cantidad;
            'total:'$producto->cantidad*$producto->precio''
        }
    }
    '
</p>
```

Generalmente se empieza por HTML, escribiendo como si estuvieras en un editor de textos, usando las etiquetas.

Te dejo más o menos un boceto de cómo ir construyendo tu html combinado con PHP.

```
<html lang="en">
   <head> 
      <title>Prueba de correo</title> 
   </head> 
   <body>
      .....
      <p>Dejas el body abierto y vas agregando lo que quieras en él</p>

<?php
//Inicio de un bloque PHP
//En el bloque de PHP puedes iniciar una variable que irías concatenando
$html="Algo que mostraré luego en el body";

//Mas operaciones PHP...
    foreach ($carritoObtenido as $producto) {
...
        $html=. "Agrego cosas del bucle for a la variable html creada antes";
}

//Cierre de bloque PHP
?>

<div><p>Aquí más HTML</p></div>

<?php
//Abro otro bloque PHP, puedo abrir todos los que quiera.
$html=. "<p>Concateno más cosas para mi variable</p>";
echo $html; //Al fin digo todo lo que tenía acumulado en $html. Puedo usar también print_r...
//Cierre de mi otro bloque PHP
?>

     <p>Ahora voy a cerrar el body</p>
     <p>Luego cerraré el html, el cual debe tener sólo una etiqueta de apertura y otra de cierre, no varias.</p>
     <p>¿Pero por qué no aparece aquí lang="en" ?... Porque eso se pone al inicio del HTML, no al final. Ah, y puede ser lang="es" si tu página es en español</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Post-Data:**

Como ves, el HTML se va construyendo paso a paso, evitando que se repitan varias etiquetas del tipo `<html>` o del tipo `<body>`.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es que no puedes meter un foreach en una cadena y por lo tanto esto da sintax error.

```
    <p> 
Usted ha comprado los siguientes productos;
'foreach ($carritoObtenido as $producto) {
```

Haz el foreach fuera de la declaración y guarda el resultado en una variable.
Y luego usa por ejemplo un implode para sacar los resultados o como te venga mas cómodo.